# $x^3 + 5x + 6 = 3\cdot 2^{1+x-k} $

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

Does anyone know how to solve 
$$n^3 + 5n + 6 = 3\cdot 2^{1+n-k} $$
where n,k are natural numbers?
I was told that there are prime number arguments that can be used but I am totally stuck. It is a subsection of a non-graded exercise sheet whose date is passed but I would still like to know how to do it. I also know that a pair of solutions are $n=7,k=1$ and $n=23,k=12$.

Many thanks.

Comment: factorize the polynomial and use GCD of factors...

Answer (score 2):

**HINT:**

$$n^3 + 5n + 6 = 3\cdot 2^{1+n-k} $$

We note that $-1$ is a root of the cubic equation $n^3 + 5n + 6 = 0$.

$$(n+1)(n^2-n+6) = 3\cdot 2^{1+n-k} $$
$$(n+1)\{n(n-1)+6\} = 3\cdot 2^{1+n-k} $$
$$n(n+1)(n-1)+6(n+1) = 3\cdot 2^{1+n-k} $$

A few more steps added:

$$\frac{n(n+1)(n-1)}{6}+\frac{(n+1)}{1} =  2^{n-k} $$
$$\frac{n(n+1)(n-1)}{3!}+\frac{(n+1)}{1!} =  2^{n-k} $$
$$\binom{n+1}{3}+\binom{n+1}{1} =  2^{(n+1)-k-1} $$
$$\binom{n}{3}+\binom{n}{1} =  2^{n-k-1} $$

See if this helps.

Comment: It yields that $\displaystyle{m\choose3}+{m\choose1}$ is a power of two, where $m=n+1.$

Comment: Sorry, even after expanding the equation I am still lost, how do you know that it is a power of 2?

Comment: @RupertGillyweed See my edit. I have updated my answer.